# CS50 problem 1 clang-7: error: no such file or directory: 'hello.c' clang-7: error: no input files

Tags: cs50

I'm new to coding and I always received this error every time. Can anyone help me to fix this?

[image: the image is here guys]

Comment: Problem solved, I watched a yt video about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are currently in the directory hello. However, hello.c is inside the directory pset1, not hello.